# How to show Matlab local documentation in system browser when pressing F1?

Tags: browser, documents, matlab, help-files

I'm using Windows7 and Matlab R2013a on my PC.
I find it impossible to copy/paste in Matlab's *window help* or *help browser*:
[image]
[image]

so I click **Get Page Address** and copy the command:
`web([docroot '/matlab/ref/plot.html'])` and add arg `'-browser'` to show the local doc file in my system browser:

```
>> web([docroot '/matlab/ref/plot.html'], '-browser')
```

yet that's quite troublesome! So is there any way to show the local docs file conveniently in my **system browser** when I press F1? Thx in advance ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with this question and I think I may have found what you're looking for. You can achieve the following by creating a shortcut at MATLAB and coding there. Label it with the name you desire and then you can run it by simply clicking on it.

Regarding the code, I must say that I used unconventional strategies but very efficient ones and I've only tested it in Windows, but you could do it Unix systems too, by changing the specific implementation.

1. Prompt the user to input the desired documentation:

   `helpdoc=input('Input the doc file: ','s');`

Then run a system command (DIR) to find the .html file that Matlab documentation uses.
Since the default documentation directory is available from docroot function, one can get the string that must be passed to system function in Matlab, by concatening the dir command as follows:

```
DirCmd=['dir /s /b "',docroot,'\',helpdoc,'html'];
```

The options /s /b are used for looking for the .html file in all subdirectories of docroot and showing up the bare content (fullpath of file). You can get more information in here: https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Finding+Files+and+Counting+Lines+at+the+Windows+Command+Prompt/2244

```
[Status,CmdOut]=system(DirCmd);
```

The system command output issued is assigned to a character array. For
multiples matches, one must filter that array and separate into
individual paths. For that purpose one can use REGEXP function with the
splitting option.

```
Paths=regexp(CmdOut,'.html','split')
```

This will return a cell array with numel=numel(strings)+1 (an extra cell is presented with null content) without the spliting term. So now me must concatenate it with the spliting term and open it in the system browser.

`for ii=1:numel(Paths)-1;
    DocWeb=[Paths{ii},'.html'];
    web(DocWeb,'-browser');
end`

I have tested this looking for doc in documentation and it took 0.7266 sec in my QuadCore 16Gb RAM computer to display the two webpages in my system browser (Chrome), regarding doc and doc for symbolic math toolbox.

I hope this helps,
Kudos.